# Contadores não estão sendo incrementados no código

Tags: c, if, for, switch, else

Estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades com o trecho de código abaixo:

A chamada dessa função é:

`cache = OperaCache(true , endereco, op, cache, descricao, read_hits, read_misses, write_hits, write_misses);`

```
VETOR_CACHE OperaCache(bool contar, unsigned long long int endereco, char op, VETOR_CACHE cache, CACHEDESC descricao, int *read_hits, int *read_misses, int *write_hits, int *write_misses)

clock_t tempo_menor = clock();//tempo maior que os outros
int trocaIndex=-1, indexRead=-1, indexWrite=-1;//inicia sem troca
bool readAchou=false, writeAchou=false;
unsigned int i;

for(i=0; i<descricao.number_of_lines; i++)
{
    if(index==cache.vetor[i].index)
    {
        switch (op)
        {
            case 'R':
                if(!readAchou && (tag==cache.vetor[i].tag))
                {
                    readAchou=true;
                    indexRead=i;
                }
                break;
            case 'W':
                if(!writeAchou)
                {
                    if(tag==cache.vetor[i].tag)
                    {
                        writeAchou=true;
                        indexWrite=i;
                    }
                    else if(cache.vetor[i].time<=tempo_menor)
                    {
                        tempo_menor=cache.vetor[i].time;
                        trocaIndex=i;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("Operacao invalida encontrada.");            
        }   
    }   
}

switch (op)
{
    case 'R':   
        if(readAchou)
        {
            if((strcmp(descricao.replacement_policy,"LRU")) == 0) 
            cache.vetor[indexRead].time=clock();
            if(contar)  
                *read_hits+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(contar)
                *read_misses+=1;
            cache = OperaCache(false, endereco, 'W', cache, descricao, read_hits, read_misses, write_hits, write_misses);
        }
        break;
    case 'W':
        if(writeAchou)
        {
            cache.vetor[indexWrite].time=clock();
            if(contar)
                *write_hits+=1;
        }
        else if(trocaIndex>-1)
        {
            if(contar)  
            *write_misses+=1;
            cache.vetor[trocaIndex].tag=tag;
            cache.vetor[trocaIndex].time=clock();
        }
        break;
    default: printf("Operacao invalida encontrada.");
}
```

A saída deveria ser:

1. Read hits:64445
2. Read misses:158
3. Write hits:44056
4. Write misses:315

Porém, por algum motivo está sendo:

1. Read hits:64603
2. Read misses:0
3. Write hits:44371
4. Write misses:0

Antes:

> Resumindo, meu problema está (imagino) nas flags `readAchou`, `writeAchou` e/ou `contar` que por algum motivo estão pulando os casos misses e considerando tudo hits...

Corrigindo, o erro realmente está na flag `contar`, porém não faço ideia de como corrigi-lo.

Comment: Outras partes do código são irrelevantes para a dúvida...

Comment: google : "Como debugar um código"

Comment: Será que você consegue fazer um exemplo menorzinho e mais fácil de entender? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @hugomg Beleza, faço um logo logo e posto aqui.

Comment: Você que passa a váriavel boolean contar, e você só a consulta, então não faz muito sentido estar dando pau. Tenta colocar uns print em baixo de cada check da contar, identificando qual parte do código ele entrou e qual o valor da váriavel, dessa forma você começa a entender melhor o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Na assinatura da função você define:
int *read_hits, int *read_misses, int *write_hits, int *write_misses
ou seja ponteiros para inteiro.

Na chamada da função não fica claro que você esteja passando ponteiros para as variáveis.